# How to modify a computer's offline registry from WINPE?

Tags: windows, regedit, winpe

I need to make changes on my registry without using the OS software, and need to do it with WINPE. However when WINPE is ready to work and I am trying to open regedit.exe it shows me only current OS information, actually the WINPE information.

So how to use WinPE as an offline registry editor?

Answer (score 19):

Load the necessary registry hives:

- in Registry Editor (`regedit`), select either HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE or HKEY_USERS, then click *File → Load Hive*, open the hive file, and input a temporary name for it;
- in command line, use `reg load HKLM\temp-name path-to-hive`
  or `reg load HKU\temp‑name path-to-hive`.

The hive files are located in:

- most of `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE` corresponds to files in `%SystemRoot%\system32\config`:

  - `HKLM\SAM` – file `SAM`
  - `HKLM\SECURITY` – file `SECURITY`
  - `HKLM\Software` – file `software`
  - `HKLM\SYSTEM` – file `system`
  - the special "system" user's registry (e.g. login screen, etc.) – file `default`
- each user's personal registry (i.e. their `HKEY_CURRENT_USER`) is located in file `NTUSER.DAT` in their profile directory (e.g. `C:\Users\grawity\NTUSER.DAT`);

  - however, `HKCU\Software\Classes` is stored in the file `AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\UsrClass.dat`.

A list of currently loaded hives is at `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\hivelist`.

Comment: what about HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT ? Can't we load it ?

Comment: I found that HKCR is actually `classes` key under `software` hive.

Comment: @Haplo: On Windows XP and later, it's a merged view of `HKCU\Software\Classes` _and_ `HKLM\Software\Classes`. The former is a separate hive, the latter isn't.

Comment: You don't mention HKEY_USERS that contains default values for all users. I read it corresponds to NTUSER.dat, but not the one in the user directory. Is it correct?

Comment: @OlafM: Not quite. HKEY_USERS doesn't have any information by itself, all it has is sub-hives for each user. For example, `HKU\S-1-5-21-…-1103` corresponds to `C:\Users\grawity\ntuser.dat`, and `HKU\.default` corresponds to `C:\Windows\System32\config\DEFAULT`. (Note that [`.default` **is not** the default user](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2007/03/02/1786493.aspx) and **does not** contain "default values for all users". It's actually the "system" user.)