# Is there any way to access registry of a Windows back up?

Tags: google-chrome, windows-registry, windows-backup, windows-7-backup

The day before yesterday my hard drive has died (MBR could not be read; all attempts to recover it proved to be futile).

All right, I was smart enough to back up all my data regularly (that included even system partition, just in case), so I did not loose any thing. So far so good.

However, there is one thing that I may have lost. I am talking about tabs opened in Chrome (I belong to category of people who like to have a lot of tabs opened).

It looks like there is a way to recover the tabs (the whole profile, actually, but I care about tabs only). It is described [here](https://workconsultants.com/blog/move-google-chrome-profiles-to-a-new-computer/). It requires exporting/importing a specific registry key, though (copying the «User data» directory is not enough, I have tried). So here comes the question: can I access the registry of my Windows 7 backup?

Comment: @Robert I am sorry, I don't know what to say. Apparently, I am not that tech savvy to understand what is written in that thread. WinPE stands for «Windows Preinstallation Environment». Do you think it has some thing in common with my problem?

Comment: Windows PE is just a "lightweight Windows" that can be booted from the CD/USB stick. But that is totally irrelevant to you. Just concentrate on the part that deals with loading the registry hives from a offline Windows installation. For that it does not matter if you have a full Windows or a WinPE.

Comment: @Robert It has worked! Thank you very much for helping.

Answer (score 0):

Please see [How to modify a computer's offline registry from WINPE?](https://superuser.com/questions/636055/how-to-modify-a-computers-offline-registry-from-winpe) for answer on how to extract keys from an off-line registry. The credit goes to Robert (please see comment feed).